# Employer changed my Roth 401k to a traditional 401k. Can they do that?

Tags: united-states, 401k, employment, roth-401k

My HR lady changed my Roth 401K to the traditional 401K without asking me and told me to correct it on my login with ADP.

I don't want the traditional 401K.

- Can they force me to do the traditional 401K?
- Can I make them fix it since they did it without my permission?

Comment: You need to check on current balances for your retirement account to verify that the money is going where you expect. Most companies have a website where you can verify your deposits, see the company match.

Answer (score 3):

> Can they force me to do the traditional 401K?

Yes. Employers don't *have to* offer the Roth option.

That said, if they do - they cannot change your election on their own.

> Can I make them fix it since they did it without my permission ?

If the Roth option is no longer offered by your employer - there's nothing much you can do about it. If it is still offered - you can insist on it.

Comment: The ADP agent told us to decide in the beginning and there is an option for it online still. what is the difference to the employer is I choose ROTH or not?

Comment: My main problem is I decided to do the 401K because the agent said we could do a Roth. I don't want a traditional one. What rights do I have with being treated like a leaf in the wind? You said if they do not offer it any longer, they just started the 401K plan 6 months ago and I had it as Roth for the first 3. I think my HR lady is uninformed and might not know what a Roth is.

Comment: Agreed with littleadv, also - (a) if the company offers both flavors, you can convert from the traditional 401(k) to Roth. There will be a bit of underwithholding on taxes, but that should be minimal, and will fix the issue so long as fuure deposits are to the Roth. (b) - asking, does the company offer a match? If not, what is the expense within the fund you are invested in? It's easy for expenses to wipe out the benefit of the Roth 401(k) especially if there's no match.

Comment: @David it very well may be that your HR lady is uninformed, if they just started offering 401k.

Comment: The company matches 5% match. I only put in 5% which is the min to get the match. they only do 5%  I am unaware of fees.

Comment: @David match is **never** Roth. Just to make sure you know that. Match will always be deposited in the pre-tax account.

Comment: @littleadv So I can put mine in Roth and theirs goes in a traditional?

Comment: @David yes, that's how it works.

Comment: @littleadv is correct, but there should also be a conversion option, i.e. you can convert the traditional 401(k) funds to the Roth side and pay the tax due. A good strategy if you are in a lower bracket now, and are comfortable to pay the tax.

Comment: If an employee contributed to a Roth 401k, that is post-tax money.  If the employer now changes the 401k plan so that the Roth option is no longer available, and demands that the funds already in the Roth side be converted to Traditional 401k funds, does the employee now have a _basis_ in the Traditional 401k? If not, the original contributions will be taxed again when they are withdrawn from the Traditional 401k.

Comment: @Dilip Roth cannot be converted back to traditional. What's in Roth - remains in Roth forever. The changes may only affect new contributions.